# Simple question - new to graph theory, what does this notation mean?

Tags: graph-theory, notation

I am very new to graph theory and don't fully understand the following notation:

Let $G_I = (V, E_I)$ be the incomparibility graph with
$E_I = \{ [x,y]:x,y \in V, \ dist(x,y) < D,\ y > x \}$

What does the condition $y>x$ here change? Consider a matrix $A_{xy}$. What does the sum

$$B_x = \sum_{\substack{y \ \in \ V\\ [x,y]\ \notin \ E_I}} \ A_{xy}$$

mean? In particular what does the condition on the second line change? Is this no longer the sum of all the columns in $A$?

Comment: Hi welcome to MSE. This sounds intriguing, but currently it seems no one can answer this without more context. For an abstract graph $(V, E)$ the notation $y > x$ with $y, x \in V$ makes no sense. Elements of the vertex set $V$ are just dots, with no ordering on them. So apparently the sentence you quote comes from the description of a very special graph where $V$ is described earlier as being a subset of some other set with extra structure, e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ or something else. Can you paste into your answer all the information we have about this graph, in particular what $V$ is?